# Missing attributes in the WeldJointDef class in LibGdx

Tags: libgdx, box2d, game-physics, jbox2d

In the original Box2D API, the WeldJointDef class has two Attributes that I couldn't find in the  LibGdx gdx.physics.box2d.joint.WeldJointDef class which are:

 - frequencyHz.

 - DampingRatio.

modifying these two attributes give more flexibility to the joint.

Is there any way to access these attributes ?
 



[LibGdx gdx.physics.box2d.joints.WeldJointDef](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/joints/WeldJointDef.html)

Comment: There isn't. You could file a feature request on the issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks @dermetfan. I received your answer from your AskMe.fm account.

Comment: I added these fields yesterday, they should be in the current SNAPSHOT and will be in the next release.

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/commit/94559d6b1d382028ad8599271a1fa91c04599651

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These features have been added to the LibGdx API.